# Neural network: Just some regression?

Tags: neural-network

I just started reading about neural networks. I thought they are something magic and extremly intelligent, but at the end of the day it just seems to be a large math function with many "undefined" constants? The learning is just another way for some kind of (more or less "stupid") regression? Is this true? For me this seems not to be very brilliant, so i am a bit surprised why this works that well.

Thank you very much

Comment: Before i thought this too, but now i think our brains work completely different.

Comment: it is not really regression, especially not when it comes to modern networks which have state, memory, attention mechanism etc. yes, we started with regressors and basic space partitioning 60 years ago, but this is a very small picture. similarly to the brain which could be simplified as "this is just bunch of electrical impulses traveling between neurons" or even deeper "just a few chemical reactions causing differences in potentials". The funny thing though, "just a regression" can probably model a perfect simulator of the world. The question is **how to learn**, this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks:) This sounds reasonable. Good argumentation:)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been proved that an artificial neural network with just one hidden layer is a *universal approximator*; that is, under proper parameterisation, it can approximate any continuous function (see [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)). More importantly, as the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network) mentions:

> Work by Hava Siegelmann and Eduardo D. Sontag has provided a proof that a specific recurrent architecture with rational valued weights (as opposed to full precision real number-valued weights) has the full power of a **Universal Turing Machine** using a finite number of neurons and standard linear connections.

This means that, at least in theory, a neural net is as much as clever as your expensive PC. And this is true without taking into account all modern extensions, e.g. as in Long-Short Term Memory networks. As one of the comments mentions, though, the real problem is *learnability*, i.e. how to find the right set of parameters for the task under consideration.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt know this:)!